# python tuples and lists. A tuple that refuses to convert

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I need to know WHY this fails:

```
class ConfigurationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ConfigurationError, self).__init__(self, args)

        self.args = list(args)
        # Do some formatting on the message string stored in self.args[0]
        self.args[0]=self.__prettyfi(self.args[0])

    def __prettyfi(self, arg):
        pass
        # Actual function splits message at word
        # boundaries at pos rfind(arg[1:78]) if len(arg) >78
        # it does this by converting a whitespace char to a \n
```

When I run the code, i receive the following msg:
`<snip>
ConfigurationError.py", line 7, in __init__
self.args[0]=self.__prettyfi(self.args[0])
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

I edited the line no. to match this code sample.

I do not understand why `self.args = list(args)` does not correctly unpack the tuple into the list at line 5.

(I have a sneaking suspicion I am failing to remember something super-basic...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Exception.args` is a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors); it hooks [`__set__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__) to turn *anything* you assign to `self.args` into a tuple.

So, as soon as you assign your list to `self.args`, the descriptor converts it back to a tuple. It's not that your `list()` call failed, it's just that `Exception.args` is special.

`BaseException.args` is documented to be a tuple, and in Python 2, exception objects support slicing:

```
>>> ex = Exception(1, 2)
>>> ex.args
(1, 2)
>>> ex[0]
1
```

Exceptions are also supposed to be immutable; keeping the `.args` attribute a tuple helps keep them so. Moreover, the `__str__` handler for exceptions expects `.args` to be a tuple, and setting it to something else has [led to strange bugs in the past](http://bugs.python.org/issue610610).

Comment: Is there any technical reason why it is a descriptor?

Comment: @Tinctorius: Exceptions are immutable, and `args` must be too. Moreover, `Exception.args` is documented to be a tuple.

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrr...thank you.  Guess ill for loop unpack it then. Unless someone knows a better way....?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That makes sense. So, `tuple` is to `list` as `frozenset` is to `set`?

Comment: @Tinctorius: Yes, except that `tuple()` predates `set`/`frozenset` by eons, of course. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry - that typo annoyed me - +1 for great analysis and explanation as always :)

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I appreciate clean-ups of my bad spelling and grammar greatly!

Comment: +1, but this still rubs me the wrong way a little.  I can't find it documented anywhere that it's a *descriptor* -- Though the documentation that it's a `tuple` is easy enough to find.  It seems to me that there are lots of places in the standard library where a user defined subclass could change the documented type of something.  Why should this be special? -- Although, it's probably explicitly stated *somewhere*.  Jython behaves the same way.

Comment: @mgilson: See [the C code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/58ac62bc3cd5/Objects/exceptions.c#l301); `.args` cannot be deleted either.

Comment: You're right, it's pretty easy to see this stuff in the C-code, but the C-code doesn't define python.  Python is a *language specification* -- The C-code is only one *implementation* of that specification.  I suppose since I spend a lot of time with compiled languages like Fortran and C on a variety of different machines, I get a little bogged down in compiler compatibility -- Which is the same thing as being careful with different python implementations really ...

Comment: @mgilson: Yup, I agree that this isn't documented very clearly; I haven't yet found anything better than the [Exceptions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: @mgilson: as it turns out, [I may have been the cause of this](http://bugs.python.org/issue610610). I discovered, way back when, ways to make the Python interpreter go wonky (throw an unhandled exception into the works) when setting `.args` to `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- It's therapeutic to take responsibility for your actions :-P.  And as a side note, it looks like you've been working with Python *A LOT* longer than I have (which makes me feel a little better about myself when you answer *every* question that I have no clue where to even start).  When I started, Python2.7 was just coming out ...